# Tooltip not displaying on focus in angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-tooltip

We are using a custom kendo tooltip (created as a component) and on hover it is displaying the message but when we tab and it has the focus it is not,
I have written a function when the focus is on the icon and it even calls that function on focus but how to proceed from then.
could someone please help me with this.

```
<app-cus-tooltip
id=customtip
[iconType]=“‘info’”
[msgkey]=“‘custominfo’” 
class=“appicons”
tabindex=0
(focusin)=doahover($event)
>
</app-cus-tooltip>



doahover($event){
// what to do here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the `focusin` event, you're missing the quotes (`""`).

```
(focusin)="doahover($event)"
```

In your function, you could now dynamically create the Tooltip component:

```
constructor(private _viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}

openTooltip(): void {
  this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(MyComponent)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Joe, but I already have a component for tooltip and I need to display the info. So how to do this

Comment: You want to display the info in your tooltip? Try my code snippet and replace `MyComponent` with your Tooltip Component